# Trying to Make a Quiz

Tags: python, count

So I am trying to run a program on python3 that asks basic addition questions using random numbers. I have got the program running however, I wanted to know if there was a way I could count the occurrences of "Correct" and "Wrong" so I can give the person taking the quiz some feedback on how they did.

```
import random

num_ques=int(input('Enter Number of Questions:'))
while(num_ques < 1):
   num_ques=int(input('Enter Positive Number of Questions:'))

   for i in range(0, (num_ques)):
      a=random.randint(1,100) 
      b=random.randint(1,100) 
      answer=int(input(str(a) + '+' + str(b) + '='))
      sum=a+b
      if (answer==sum):
        print ('Correct')
      else:
        print ('Wrong.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `dict` to store counts for each type, increment them when you come across each type, and then access it after to print the counts out.

Something like this:

```
import random

stats = {'correct': 0, 'wrong': 0}

num_ques=int(input('Enter Number of Questions:'))
while(num_ques < 1):
   num_ques=int(input('Enter Positive Number of Questions:'))

   for i in range(0, (num_ques)):
      a=random.randint(1,100) 
      b=random.randint(1,100) 
      answer=int(input(str(a) + '+' + str(b) + '='))
      sum=a+b
      if (answer==sum):
        print ('Correct')
        stats['correct'] += 1
      else:
        print ('Wrong.')
        stats['wrong'] += 1


print "results: {0} correct, {1} wrong".format(stats['correct'], stats['wrong'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
import random
def ask_float(prompt):
    while True:
        try: return float(input(prompt))
        except: print("Invalid Input please enter a number")

def ask_question(*args):
    a = random.randint(1,100)
    b = random.randint(1,100)
    op = random.choice("+-/*")
    answ = {"+":operator.add,"-":operator.sub,"*":operator.mul,"/":operator.div}[op](a,b)
    return abs(answ - ask_float("%s %s %s = ?"%(a,op,b)))<0.01 

num_questions = 5
answers_correct = sum(map(ask_question,range(num_questions)))
print("You got %d/%d Correct!"%(answers_correct,num_questions))
```